# How do I convert 'cv::Mat' to 'double'?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, opencv3.0

I am trying to implement [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d/897677#897677) from math.stackexchange in eclispe with C++ and OpenCV 3.0.0 (beta).
I am using the code below for that.

```
Mat a = (Mat_<double>(1,3) <<   rotationMatrix1.at<double>(2,0), rotationMatrix1.at<double>(2,1), rotationMatrix1.at<double>(2,2));
Mat b = (Mat_<double>(1,3) <<   rotationMatrix2.at<double>(2,0), rotationMatrix2.at<double>(2,1), rotationMatrix2.at<double>(2,2));

Mat f = (Mat_<double>(1,3) << a , (b-(a.dot(b))*a)/norm(b-(a.dot(b))*a),a.cross(b));
Mat f1 = f.inv(DECOMP_CHOLESKY);

Mat g = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << a.dot(b), - norm(a.cross(b)), 0,  norm(a.cross(b)), a.dot(b), 0,  0,0,1);

Mat u = f1.inv(DECOMP_CHOLESKY) * g * f1;
```

when I compile this results in the following error:

> /include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:2827:15: error: invalid cast from type 'cv::MatExpr' to type 'double'
>   /include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:2827:15: error: invalid cast from type 'cv::Mat' to type 'double'

So the problem probably lies in this line:

```
Mat f = (Mat_<double>(1,3) << a , (b-(a.dot(b))*a)/norm(b-(a.dot(b))*a),a.cross(b));
```

because "a" and "(b-(a.dot(b))*a)/norm(b-(a.dot(b))*a)" are not 'double'.
So my question is how would I convert these to 'double' in a correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better readability let's rewrite your line

```
Mat f = (Mat_<double>(1,3) << a , (b-(a.dot(b))*a)/norm(b-(a.dot(b))*a),a.cross(b));
```

to this:

```
cv::Mat t0 = b - a.dot( b ) * a; // size: 1x3
cv::Mat t1 = t0 / norm(t0);      // size: 1x3
cv::Mat t2 = a.cross(b);         // size: 1x3
Mat f = (Mat_<double>(1,3) << a , t1 , t2);
//                            ^   ^^   ^^ these are 1x3 matrices (== 9 double value),
//                                        but matrix f expects 3 doubles.
```

Looking at the [math stack question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d/897677#897677) that you reference, the function

```
FFi = @(A,B) [ A (B-dot(A,B)*A)/norm(B-dot(A,B)*A) cross(B,A) ];
```

returns a 3-by-3 matrix, so in any case `Mat_<double>(1,3)` is wrong.

To solve this problem create a 3-by-3 matrix and then assign the values of the temporary variables above to the columns of that matrix:

```
cv::Mat1d f(3,3);
f( cv::Rect( 0, 0, 1, 3 ) ) = a.t(); // transposed, cf. note below
f( cv::Rect( 0, 0, 2, 3 ) ) = t1.t(); // transposed, cf. note below
f( cv::Rect( 0, 0, 3, 3 ) ) = t2.t(); // transposed, cf. note below
```

**Note:** Pay attention to your vectors which are 1-by-3, not 3-by-1 as in the referenced question. If you're lucky this triggers runtime errors. If you're not, your code compiles and runs but your result are wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I had overlooked that f is a 3x3 matrix

Answer (score 0):

"Converting" them is the wrong thing to do. You have a error in your expression. One of OpenCV's functions takes a double and you pass a matrix. Now that one line contains about a dozen function calls (with all the operators included) so it's hard to pick the one at fault here.

Just write out definitions of temporary variables for the different sub-expressions. You will probably find that one of those sub-expressions, who you think evaluates to a double, actually evaluates to a matrix. That expression is at fault. Don't "fix" it to make the error go away. Fix it so that the result becomes meaningful.

E.g. you may have forgotten to take the determinant of a matrix somewhere, and we wouldn't have an idea - we're not domain experts. Neither is the C++ compiler. It doesn't know anything about determinants, it just detects a type mismatch. And obviously, taking the determinant of a matrix is not a "conversion"